# Create GCP IAM to subscribe and also list only a dedicated subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I want to achieve that an extra created service-account is only possible to subscribe to a certain pubsub-subscription.

And also, when one uses this service-account for listing all subscriptions, it should also see only the "dedicated" subscription.

I've created on the subscription a permission which have to test the Pub/Sub Admin role

[image]

Then I check the listing with

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

project_id = "project101"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    './myServiceAccount.json')

project_path = f"projects/{project_id}"

with pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials) as subscriber:
    for subscription in subscriber.list_subscriptions(
            request={"project": project_path}
    ):
        print(subscription.name)
```

but it results in a 403.

As you see I need this for splunk, but I don't want to open too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list Pub/Sub subscriptions requires the permission `projects.subscriptions.list`.

That permission must be granted at the **Project level** or a higher resource. The principal with that permission will be able to list all subscriptions. You cannot limit them to a select few.

You can review the available permissions and where they can be applied here:

[Google Cloud Pub/Sub Required Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control)

Comment: Thanks! Yes it's working. But it is a pity that it is not also configurable for "list" below.

Have created a TopLevel with List and on subscription level with consume.

Thanks!